# Having one list of items which is shown few times, is there any technique which let to sort each representation independently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have one list\source of tracks, which is shown few times on different pages. I want to allow users to sort this list independently (per page).

I could create few copies of this list, but the problem is that this list can be changed (add\remove\rename tracks and so on), so in this case few copies of this list seems to be not a good solution, because such changes must be applied to all copies of the list.

Is there any technique which allows to sort tracks independently, having just one source of tracks?

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/w6q7l5nqrk)

Comment: Have a look how EventEmitters work. Whenever you update the main list, emit an event. Then all the different page components could copy / sort the list and display the updated version

Answer (score 0):

You got basically two options:

1) Notify all components that got their own sorted version of the list when the list changes, so that they can copy the changed list and sort / display it. For that you need a way of emitting events, e.g. as a mixin class:

```
const EventEmitter = Parent => class EventEmitter extends Parent {
  constructor(...args) {
     super(...args);
     this._emitters = {};
  }

  trigger(evt, ...args) {
    (this._emitters[evt] || []).forEach(emitter => emitter(...args));
  }

  on(evt, handler) {
    (this._emitters[evt] || (this._emitters[evt] = [])).push(handler);
  }
};
```

Then you can proxy an array, so that on every change an update event is triggered:

```
 const ChangeEmitter = Parent => {
    const Mixin = EventEmitter(Parent);
    return (...args) => new Proxy(
       new Mixin(...args),
       {
          set(obj, prop, value) {
             const result = Reflect.set(...arguments);
             obj.trigger("update", obj);
             return result;
          }
       }
    );
 };
```

That looks very complex, but now we can do this:

```
 // Our source of truth:
 const base = new ChangeEmitter(Array);

  // One of the functions that renders the data:
 function renderSorted(array) {
   const sorted = array.sort();
   document.body.innerHTML = sorted;
 }
 renderSorted(base); // Initial render
 base.on("update", renderSorted);

 base[0] = 1;
```

So whenever we update the base array, all renderers will get called again and everything can get updated.

---

2) Create a few sorted arrays and apply every mutation to all of them. For that we need a sorted array:

```
class SortedArray extends Array {
  constructor(sorter, ...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.sorter = sorter;
    this.sort(sorter);
  }

  // Do insertion sort
  add(el) {
    let index = 0;
    while(index <= this.length && this.sorter(el, this[index]) > 0) index++;
    this splice(index, 0, el);
  }

  remove(el) {
     this.splice(this.indexOf(el), 1);
  }
}
```

And a way to change multiple arrays in parallel:

```
 const unifyArrays = (...arrays) => ({
   add(el) {  arrays.forEach(arr => arr.add(el)); },
   remove(el) { arrays.forEach(arr => arr.remove(el)); }
 });
```

So now you can do:

```
const sorted = new SortedArray((a, b) => a - b);
const reversed = new SortedArray((a, b) => b - a);

const base = unifyArrays(sorted, reversed);

base.add(1);
```

For sure you can combine both approaches, so that evenrs will be emitted when the arrays get changed.